# Transpile ES6+ to ES5 with webpack-dev-server in real time

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack-dev-server, ecmascript-5, webpack-4

I want to have a simple setup based on webpack and webpack-dev-server to write ES6 code - classes, arrow functions and see the result straight away in the browser. That works. But how to create a ES5 version of source file in real time. So that it is human readable. Here is what I have:

package.json

```
{
"name": "sand",
"description": "js project",
"version": "1.0.0",
"author": "me",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --open",
    "build": "webpack"
},
"dependencies": {},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.20.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
      entry: "./index.js",
      output: { filename: "bundle.js" },
      mode: 'development',
      module: {
         rules: [   
            {
               test: /\.js?$/,
               exclude: /(node_modules)/,
               loader: "babel-loader",
               options: { "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"] }
            }  
         ]
      }
};
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Sandbox</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <div id="container"></div>
       <script src="bundle.js"></script>
     </body>
   </html>
```

.babelrc

```
 {
   "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
 }
```

Currently this setup runs in browser and makes hot updates if I write and save js code. But I dont have any ES5 version.